# como devo fazer para o código python que fiz para loteria não repetisse os números no mesmo quando coloco 5 par e 1 impar para dar o resultado do jogo

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint

n = int(input('Número par: '))
b = int(input('Número impar: '))
quant = int(input('quantos grupo são: '))

def method_name():
    def sorteia(lista):
        cont = 0
        c = 0
        while True:
            num = randint(1, 61)
            if num % 2 == 0 not in lista:
                lista.append(num)
                cont += 1            
            if cont >= n:            
                break
        while tuple:
            num = randint(1,60)
            if num % 2 == 1 not in lista:
                lista.append(num)
                c += 1            
            if c >= b:
                break
        lista.sort()
        jogos.append(lista[:])
        lista.clear()
        
    lista = list()
    jogos = list()
    sorteia(lista)
    for i, l in enumerate(jogos):
        print(f'jogos {i + 1} : {l}')
    return i, jogos, l, lista, sorteia

i, jogos, l, lista, sorteia = method_name()
```

Comment: Para que serve a variável `quant`?

Answer (score 1):

Pensando que você possui os números fixados de 1 até 60. Acredito que criar o conjunto de pares e o conjunto de ímpares antes, poupa muito trabalho

```
import random

pares = range(2, 61, 2)
impares = range(1, 61, 2)

qtd_par = int(input('Número par: '))
qtd_impar = int(input('Número impar: '))

pares_sorteados = random.sample(pares, qtd_par)
impares_sorteados = random.sample(impares, qtd_impar)

sorteados = pares_sorteados + impares_sorteados
sorteados.sort()

print(sorteados)
```

Caso você escolha 5 pares e 1 ímpar a saída será algo como o **exemplo** abaixo:

```
[4, 10, 16, 20, 39, 60]
```

Comment: O brigado por mim ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja gerar **grupos** de números que serão utilizados como palpites em jogos lotéricos, onde se deve especificar a quantidade de valores **pares** e, também, de valores ímpares.

Pois bem, em primeiro lugar observei que seu range é **range(1, 61)**. Com esta informação deduzo que o jogo lotérico esperado é **Mega Sena**. Dessa forma a **MENOR QUANTIDADE DE NÚMEROS** à ser utilizada em cada aposta (grupo) deste jogo é **6**. Neste caso, teremos de sortear 6 números que formarão cada grupo.

Outra coisa importante é saber que para realizar sorteios sem repetições precisamos utilizar o método **[sample](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample)** da bilbioteca **[random](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html)**. Além disso, devemos ter consciência que como a quantidade de números sorteados por grupo serão sempre **6**, a quantidade de números ímpares sempre será a diferença entre **6 e a quantidade de números pares**. Por isso, especificando a quantidade de números pares obteremos automaticamente a quantidade de números ímpares, isto é, não precisamos **capturar por input()** a quantidade de números ímpares.

Além disso devemos tratar a quantidade de **pares e grupos**. Existem diversas formas de realizar tal tratamento. Nesta questão vou utilizar um recurso que está disponível a partir do **Python 3.8**, que se chama **[Assignmente Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)**.

Com todas estas observações poderemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
def loterias(p, g):
    for j in range(1, g + 1):
        yield sorted(sample(range(2, 61, 2), p) + sample(range(1, 61, 2), 6 - p))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while (par := int(input('Quantidade de pares entre "1" e "6": '))) < 1 or par > 6:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

    while (grupo := int(input('Quantidade de grupos (valor maior que 0): '))) < 1:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

    resposta = loterias(par, grupo)

    for r in resposta:
        for m in r:
            print(f'{m:02}', end=' ')
        print()
```

Observe que quando executamos este código nos é solicitada a quantidade de **valores pares** que participarão de cada grupo sorteado. Esta quantidade deve ser um valor entre **1 e 6**. Enquanto o valor digitado para esta quantidade for menor que `1` ou maior que `6`, receberemos a mensagem `Valor IINVÁLIDO!` e nos é novamente solicitado o valor.

Em seguida, nos é solicitada a quantidade de grupos que serão formados. Esta quantidade deve ser maior que `0`. Enquanto o valor digitado para esta quantidade for menor que `1`, receberemos a mensagem `Valor IINVÁLIDO!` e nos é novamente solicitado o valor.

Posteriormente estas informações serão enviadas, como parâmetros, para a função **loterias()**. Chegando lá serão sorteados a quantidade de números pares e, também, a quantidade de números ímpares - que seria (6 - quantidade de números pares). Posteriormente, estes valores serão adicionados à uma lista, sendo os mesmos ordenados de forma crescente com a ajuda da função **[sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted)**.

Depois dessas operações, com ajuda do **[yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)** será montada uma função **[geradora](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)**. Em seguida, o bloco for irá exibir os resultados em ordem crescente, devidamente formatados, com dois dígitos - completando com **0** o valor faltante à esquerda.

**Testando o código**

Imagine que queremos sortear **4** grupos, onde cada um deles deve ter **5** valores pares e **1** valor ímpar. Para isso devemos executar o programa e quando for exibida a mensagem: `Quantidade de pares:` , devemos digitar:

```
5
```

...e quando for exibida a mensagem: `quantidade de grupos:`  devemos digitar:

```
4
```

Em seguida, o programa calculará os resultados e **4 grupos, de 6 números, com 5 números pares e 1 número ímpar**.

Como o sorteio é realizado de forma aleatória, uma das possíveis saídas pode ser:

```
12 24 29 30 52 60 
12 13 18 36 50 56 
05 14 18 24 54 60 
05 06 18 30 32 58
```

Observe que o resultado nos mostrou 4 grupos, com 6 valores, onde 5 deles são pares e 1 deles é ímpar, e todos organizados em ordem crescente e com dois dígitos.